# Minimizing a function with respect to a matrix, subjected to constraints

Tags: calculus, optimization, markov-chains, matrix-calculus, markov-process

I'm trying to figure out how to minimize the following function:
$$ f(P^*) = -\sum_{i}\sum_{j}P_{ij}\log(\frac{[P^*(I-\nu P^*)^{-1}]_{ij}}{P_{ij}}) $$

where the sum is over terms with nonzero entries. $P$ is some given matrix that is a properly normalized transition matrix (for some Markov chain) and $\nu$ is a positive real number.

The constraints are that $P^*$ is also a normalized transition matrix, and that $[P^*(I-\nu P^*)^{-1}]_{ij}= 0$ implies $P_{ij} = 0$.

Both the function and the constraints seem unwieldy. How would one go about finding the optimal $P^*$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stochastic matrix $(P^*)$ can be constructed
from an arbitrary matrix $(A)$ and the all-ones matrix $(J)$ as follows
$$\eqalign{
A,J &\in {\mathbb R}^{n\times n} \qquad J_{ik} = {\tt1} \\
P^* &= \frac{A}{JA} \qquad \big({\rm Elementwise\,Division}\big) \\
v &= P^*u  \qquad \big({\rm Stochastic\,Vectors}\big) \\
}$$
**NB:** Some authors define the stochastic property in terms of left multiplication, in which case the above formulas would change to
$$\eqalign{
P^* &= \frac{A}{AJ}, \qquad v^T &= u^TP^* \\
}$$
For convenience, define the matrices
$$\eqalign{
dP^* &= \frac{JA\odot dA-A\odot J\,dA}{JA\odot JA} \\
Q &= (I-\nu P^*)^{-1} \quad\implies\quad dQ = -\nu Q\,dP^*Q \\
R &= \frac{P}{P^*Q} \\
S &= \frac{\big(\nu Q^T{P^*}^T-I\big)\,RQ^T}{JA\odot JA} \\
}$$
Write the cost function and calculate its gradient with respect to
the unconstrained $A$ matrix.
$$\eqalign{
f &= -P:\log\left(\frac{P^*Q}{P}\right) \\
df &= -P:\left(\frac{dP^*Q+P^*dQ}{P^*Q}\right) \\
 &= -R:\big(dP^*Q-\nu P^*Q\,dP^*Q\big) \\
 &= \nu (P^*Q)^TRQ^T:dP^* - RQ^T:dP^* \\
 &= S:\big(JA\odot dA-A\odot J\,dA\big) \\
 &= (S\odot JA):dA - J(S\odot A):dA \\
 &= \Big(S\odot JA - J(S\odot A)\Big):dA \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}
 &= S\odot JA - J(S\odot A) \\
}$$
Setting the gradient to zero yields the equation
$$\eqalign{
S\odot JA = J(S\odot A)
}$$
which must be solved for $A$.

However, the matrix $S$ (as well as  $R,Q,P^*$)
is a function of $A$, so this equation is nonlinear. A closed-form algebraic solution is highly unlikely, so an iterative numerical solution is your best option.

Since the gradient is known, I'd suggest a gradient-descent method to solve for $A$ which minimizes $f$. Once you have that you can construct $P^*$.

In the preceding, the symbol $\odot$ denotes the elementwise/Hadamard product and a colon represents the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$

---

#### Update

The $A$ matrix used above is actually not unconstrained, 
but is itself subject to a non-negativity constraint. 

However, the derivation can be salvaged by introducing a 
truly unconstrained matrix $X$ and defining $A$ in terms of it.
$$\eqalign{
A &= \exp(X) \\
dA &= A\odot dX \\
}$$
Then in the final expression for the differential, 
perform a change of variable from $A\to X$
$$\eqalign{
df &= \Big(S\odot JA - J(S\odot A)\Big):dA \\
 &= \Big(S\odot JA - J(S\odot A)\Big):A\odot dX \\
 &= A\odot\Big(S\odot JA - \big(J(S\odot A)\big)\Big):dX \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}
 &= A\odot\Big(S\odot JA - \big(J(S\odot A)\big)\Big) \\
}$$
Use this gradient to solve for the optimal $X$ which minimizes $f$, then calculate the corresponding $A$, and ultimately $P^*$

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any references that I could read up on that solve similar kinds of problems (i.e papers using the trick of writing the stochastic matrix in terms of an unconstrained matrix)?

Comment: If you want to look up formulas, I'd suggest Bernstein's _Matrix Mathematics: Theory, Facts, and Formulas_  $\;$ If you want more theory, then Magnus and Neudecker's _Matrix Differential Calculus_  $\;$ or perhaps Hjorungnes's  _Complex-Valued Matrix Derivatives_